# Legal Memo in Latex

Tags: legal-style

I want to write a legal memo using Latex.
What class should I use in order to do this?
Is there any other advice one could offer when formatting a legal memo to my company in Latex?

Comment: Legal memos are highly subject-, country-, and language-specific. Which topic, or topics, is the memo supposed to cover? Which country are you based in? Which language do you use?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use the `letter` class perhaps, if you search for `legal memo templates` on a browser it should have templates already made, on Overleaf etc. If you go to CTAN.org too there will be ready made